# How to convert only some elements of an array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:`['14', '43.8303', '13', '44.8114', '16', '45.6076', '7', '45.6762', '2', '45.8241', '18', '46.0605', '8', '47.7897',                '4', '53.4238', '1', '53.5724', '15', '54.0245', '17', '54.1073', '9', '58.2705', '3', '61.0334', '5', '62.0799', '12', '70.6712', '11', '81.171', '10', '196.992', '6', '314.895']`

Is it possible to convert the elements on the even positions to `int` and the ones on odd positions to `float` ?

I tried it like this :

```
for i in range(36):
        if i%2==0:
            items[i] = map(int, items[i])
        else:
            items[i] = map(float,items[i])
```

However, I get this error:

> ERROR MESSAGE : ValueError: invalid literal for float():

Comment: The bigger question is - why do you want to do this? Whatever problem you are trying to solve, this seems like a strange way to go about it.

Comment: it seems you have just copied sample data incorrectly, after your edit , the code works so good.

Comment: it looks like he really wants a dictionary python3
    `i = iter(a);
    b = dict(zip(i, i))`

Answer (score 8):

A fun version (please don't use this code!):

```
from itertools import cycle
func = cycle((int, float))
new_items = [next(func)(i) for i in items]
```

**Edit**: As a more serious answer, you probably don't really *want* this kind of mixed list.  It may be more useful to use a list of pairs, with the first item of each pair being an integer and the second being a floating point number.  This data structure can be constructed from your list using

```
new_items = [(int(x), float(y)) for x, y in zip(*[iter(items)] * 2)]
```

Comment: Why not? It's the data structure that's insane, not the code.

Comment: Or: `[(int, float)[i % 2](x) for i, x in enumerate(items)]`

Comment: I can do better: `list(imap(apply, cycle((int, float)), izip(items)))`

Comment: @ecatmur: Yet another one: `[f(i) for f, i in izip(cycle((int, float)), items)]`. (Inspired by yours, but also working in Python 3.x)

Answer (score 5):

```
new_items = [float(item) if index % 2 else int(item)
             for index, item in enumerate(items)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Michael Hoffman's solution, but it might me useful to know the error in your code:

```
for i in range(36):
    if i%2==0:
        items[i] = map(int, items[i])
        # should be: items[i] = int(items[i])
    else:
        items[i] = map(float,items[i])
        # should be: items[i] = float(items[i])
```

`map` calls a function on each element of a list, but in this case, you want to call `int` and `float` on the individual elements `items[i]`, because you're already looping.

(Also, `for i in range(26)` should be `for i in range(len(items))`. Please don't use magic constants.)

Comment: Thank you too! Don said the same thing .

Answer (score 1):

using slices, you can update your list in place.  (In contrast to some of the other solutions which create a new list -- The difference is subtle and in some cases doesn't matter, but it's good to know what you're doing anyway).

```
a[::2]=map(int,a[::2])
a[1::2]=map(float,a[1::2])
```

`a[::2]` takes every other element starting from 0, `a[1::2]` takes every other element starting from 1.

Or a list comprehension if you prefer...

```
a[::2]=[int(x) for x in a[::2]]
a[1::2]=[float(x) for x in a[1::2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your solution:

```
for i in range(36):
    if i%2==0:
        items[i] = int(items[i])
    else:
        items[i] = float(items[i])
```